# trading view / Pine scripting Average of High and Low in

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to get the average high / Low of 10 day or 20 days (Number of Days =input). For this i am using for loop and the security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high). But i cannt use the security in for loop.
So how can achieve adding all the highs and dividing by number of days. Where number of days is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop is unnecessary and inefficient to achieve this in Pine. Prefer the non-repainting version and see this publication for an explanation: [How to avoid repainting when using security() - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/).

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
hlMa = sma(hl2, input(10))

repainting = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', hlMa)
plot(repainting)

// More reliable.
noRepainting = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', hlMa[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(noRepainting, "", color.orange, 6, transp = 70)
```

[image]